# Given a stochastic matrix $P$, find a markov chain $\{X_n\}$ having $P$ as its transition matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> We know that ginen a (discrete time) markov chain $\{X_n\}$, its transition matrix is stochastic.
>   Is the inverse true? I.e. given a stochastic matrix $P$, is there a (discrete time) markov chain $\{X_n\}$ having $P$ as its transition matrix?

**Attempt.** I believe so. We are dealing with an existence theorem, and my idea has been the use of Kolmogorov's extension theorem, since it guarantees the existance of a desired markov chain under certain properties. Am I on the right path?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is wrong with just defining the process to make transitions based on the current state (independent of history) and using the probabilities specified by $P$?  Equivalently, take a random walk on a graph. Kolmogorov extension theorem seems like overkill here.

Comment: Thank you! That seems reasonable!